# Folder structure - good practice

Tags: c++

I have main.cpp file, one base class (header and .cpp file for this one), and two derived classes (also with their header and .cpp files).

Is there some way that is considered a good practice of creating folder structure in C++?

In PHP I would create main.cpp in the root, folder called "Base_Class", put base's header and .cpp there, and inside of this folder I would create separate subfolders for derived classes.

Comment: Whatever works! BTW have a separate directory for unit tests.

Comment: I don't know what are the downvotes for. In PHP there were specific folder structures like PSR-0 etc, I was curious if there's anything like that in C.

Comment: I agree with you. I don't understand the -1s. This is a legit question.

Comment: @Alexandre It is rather subjective to how to organize your code - AKA open to debate.

Comment: @user2252786 - It is just a suggestion - not gospel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very simple projects, like yours, putting it all in a single folder is okay. If you get more files that are not sources or header, it might be a good idea to put sources (together with headers) in a separate folder, and e.g. documents in a separate folder, etc. When you start to get many source files, or if you find it can be slit nicely into modules, then one folder per module in the source folder..

At least that is about the way *I* do it. How *you* should do it is totally up to you. There is really no single "best practice", it's all very up to personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some input from me

```
lib/ (*.cpp .h)
include/ (class definitions *.h) <- Third party lib
prototype/ (quick tests)
doc/ (documentation,ppt)
unittest/unittest result project files
utility/utility library
Release/release binaries of project
Automation/Any automation scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

For small project (like yours) you can just put everything in single folder. Or you can put `.cpp` files in `src` folder and `.h` in `include` folder. Again this is for small project only.